# CSS Menu Nav Messed Up

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm in the process of updating a header navigation menu for a website shown here:

As you can see, the text & separators are pushed down and the menu looks off. I've tried a couple of different things to no avail. I'd like to have the text & separators vertically aligned with each other without that extra padding at the top.

**CSS**

```
/*Header Link Wrap & Align*/

#nav-wrap { 
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 52px;
    background-image: url(/nd/images/hlink-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

}


#nav {
    text-align: center;

}

#nav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}

#nav a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:arial;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 18px 9px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav a:hover {
    background-color: #ffa500;
    color: #fff9;
}




.head-divider {
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; 
    margin: 0;
    width:2px;
    height:52px;
    background-image:url(/nd/images/h-divider.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav-wrap">
    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="homes.php">Custom Homes</a></li>
    <li class="head-divider"></li>
    <li><a href="inspections.php">Inspection Services</a></li>
    <li class="head-divider"></li>
    <li><a href="energy.php">Energy Audits</a></li>
    <li class="head-divider"></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>  
</div>
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the `margin` and `padding` of the `<ul>` simply.

Add the following style to you `#nav`:

```
#nav{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: 0px is 0em is 0mm is 0 is 0 is 0.

Comment: Thanks for the tip reisio - I'll remember it in the future.